# Can I change the Datasets Dynamically within Jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I created two Databases for single report (**Oracle and PostgreSQL**) in oracle I have procedure to call a report and in PostgreSQL I have a function, how can I call single report from both databases? when I select Oracle from application it fetches data from Oracle and when I select Postgres it fetches from Postgres. What modification i should do in jasper report only?

Oracle Calling:

[image]

PostgreSQL:

[image]

Comment: You can path connection and query via Java code. You can also build report dynamically with JasperReports API

Comment: But in jasper report (report.jrxml) i am calling Oracle procedure in plsql editor where i can't call PostgreSQL function in plsql editor.